# Variable does not exist in the current context when calling a property from a different function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following model that exist within a function. One of the property is calling another function but I'm getting a variable not within scope. (EndOn.Month, EndOn.Day)

The logic behind all this is to populate the serviceYear with part of the date from EndOn properties.
I do understand the error, just not sure how to resolve this.

```
public ProgramSchedule GetProgramScheduleEditViewModel()
 {
 var newModel = new ProgramSchedule(customerProgram.RepeatBy)
   {
     EndOn = Value;
     ServiceYear = GetServiceYearWithDefault(),
    };
        return newModel;
  }

public DateTime GetServiceYearWithDefault()
 {
  int defaultYear = ((short?)GetParameterValue(ParameterConfiguration.GeneralParameterKeys.Year)) ?? 
  (int)DateTime.Now.Year;
  //End.Month and End.Now.Day is where the variable is out of scope
  DateTime Final = new DateTime(defaultYear, EndOn.Month, EndOn.Day);
  return Final;
  }
```

Comment: is it End.Month and End.Now.Dayi or is it EndOn.Month and EndOn.Now.Day?

Comment: Yeah, maybe you meant ```EndOn.Month``` instead of End.Month. We also don't see where ```Value``` comes from in ```GetProgramScheduleEditViewModel```

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance and [edit] post accordingly. It is very unclear why you expect `End` to magically show up out nowhere based on that code (or even `EndOn` if that what you meant to write)

Comment: I always wonder why, OPs are posting code that doesn't compile. `EndOn = Value;` (both Value and ;), `End.Now.Day` (probably `End.Day`), `GetServiceYearWithDefault(),` the comma, etc.. Isn't an extra effort needed to achieve this? Isn't copying and pasting easier?

Comment: Oh, there comes the `EndOn`s and EndOn.Day, but EndOn = Value; is still there.

Comment: It is  EndOn.Month, EndOn.Day that I'm having an issue with.

Comment: Ok, but where are they declared? Are these two methods inside the ProgramSchedule class? Post the full class please.

Comment: And, what is `Value`?

Comment: What happens if you do the assignments to EndOn  and ServiceYear outside the brackets? Just before `return newModel;` as `newModel.EndOn = Value;` and `newModel.ServiceYear = GetServiceYearWithDefault();`

Comment: Two different methods in within the same class that is not ProgramSchedule. Only the EndOn is declared within the ProgramSchedule. And yes it does make sense in getting this error, just have not been able to update my property model in that way. Maybe all this logic is not well explained on my part.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not gonna lie: your logic seems pretty convoluted to me. Something that would fix your problem (but would entangle things even more) would be to accept a `DateTime` as a parameter to `GetServiceYearWithDefault`, like so:

```
    public DateTime GetServiceYearWithDefault (DateTime endOn)
    {
        int defaultYear = ((short?)GetParameterValue(
            ParameterConfiguration.GeneralParameterKeys.Year)
        ) ?? (int) DateTime.Now.Year;

        DateTime Final = new DateTime(defaultYear, endOn.Month,
            endOn.Day);
        return Final;
    }
```

now you change the first method to pass the `EndOn` as the `DateTime` argument to `GetProgramScheduleEditViewModel`:

```
    public ProgramSchedule GetProgramScheduleEditViewModel ()
    {
        var newModel = new ProgramSchedule(customerProgram.RepeatBy)
        {
            EndOn = Value;
            ServiceYear = GetServiceYearWithDefault(EndOn);
        };
        return newModel;
    }
```